# why does this infinite loop occures?

Tags: javascript

when trying to get items from local storage that are named
useJSON1, useJSON2 and so on.
i get an infinite loop.

```js
var test = 0;
function loadTasks() {
    let i = 1
    let taskObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('useJSON' + i)); 
while (test < i)
    if (taskObject) {
        // do somthing;
        i++;
    } else {
        test = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug why the while condition is never met: `test < i`

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Comment: if taskObject is false, the code will not compute nothing (of interest), and if is true you got a infinite loop

Comment: I suppose you assume `taskObject` will get a new value when `i` changes (because of `.('useJSON' + i));`. It will not, `i` is a literal value here, and it is not changing the value of `taskObject` when changed later. You've to add that expression into the loop body.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your syntax, and brackets?
Should it look more like this?

```
var test = 0;
function loadTasks() {
    var i = 1;
    var taskObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('useJSON' + i)); 
    while (test < i){
        if (taskObject) {
            `do somthing`;
            i++;
            } else {
            test = i;
            }
        }
    }
```